# Openni Kinect V1 default parameters

Tags: kinect, openni, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to evaluate if a certain point in the map frame is or isn't visible to robot.
In order to do so, with the camera angles of view and the robot pose, I can verify if that point is in the camera field of view.
But that point, at some views, can be also occluded with something that is on front of it.
To verify that I need to check the depth of the pixel where that point would be. If its lower than the depth to that  point it is a sign that that point is occluded by something...
To perform these transformation from point-> pixel and to verify the field of view I need the intrinsic parameters of my Kinect V1. I don't want to perform a new calibration, since the kinect with the default values seems to be working pretty fine.

When I launch openni I receive the following messages:

```
[ WARN] [1529322621.477102624]: Camera calibration file /home/some1/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00362803930039A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1529322621.477189197]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1529322621.477267591]: Camera calibration file /home/some1/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00362803930039A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1529322621.477340809]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

I don't mind using the default camera parameters, I just need to know them to do my calculations. Do you know where are stored or defined the default kinect v1 parameters that openni is using?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294357/openni-kinect-v1-default-parameters/) by [SancheZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/34898/sanchez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry guys, took about 15 minutes after making this post to found the solution. There's a type of message: sensor_msgs/CameraInfo that contains the intrinsics matrix -> [CameraInfo](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html)
Knowing that, I saw that openni was publishing in /camera/depth_registered/camera_info those messages. You only need to perform a rostpic echo on these topic to get your camera parameters ;)

---

Originally posted by [SancheZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/34898/sanchez/) with karma: 28 on 2018-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0